# CSS: covering fixed element with z-index

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>
<div class="cover"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.cover{z-index: 10;} 
.wrap{position: relative; z-index: 1;} 
.fixed{position: fixed; display: block; z-index: 1;}
```

Exampale: http://jsfiddle.net/6fq8L/

On page scroll .cover element is hidden behind .fixed element despite its z-index property is higher. How to show .cover element above .wrap and .fixed elements so it will cover them when page is scrolled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fq8L/1/)

You need to give `cover` a `position` for `z-index` to work, e.g.

```
.cover{z-index: 10;position:relative;}
```

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of an element and its
>   descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one
>   covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an
>   element with a lower one.
>
> For a **positioned box**, the z-index property specifies:
>
> 1. The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> 2. Whether the box establishes a local stacking context.

Comment: This. You always need to combine position with z-indexing.